# ConfigureAwait and GetAwaiter changing behaviour

Tags: c#, task

I'm experimenting with Tasks.
I have

```
private async Task<string> GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return "Finished!";
}

private async Task<string> GetStringAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Finished!";
}
```

What's strange to me:

```
private void Button10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button10.Content = "GetAwaiter() GetResult() + deadlock";
    var task = GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
    var result = task.GetResult(); // deadlock
    Button10.Content = result;
}
```

I expected **NO deadlock** and **crash** on the last line because of non-UI context as it would be didn't I used GetAwaiter(), but I experience a deadlock

Next:

```
private void Button11_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button11.Content = "GetAwaiter() GetResult() No deadlock";
    var task = GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
    var result = task.GetResult(); // No deadlock
    Button11.Content = result; // No crash
}
```

Here I expected crash on the last line because of non-UI context, but it works without issues.
Doesn't *ConfigureAwait(false)* make sense when we use *GetAwaiter()*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait` configures the behaviour of the `await` keyword in the same expression. It does not affect other `await` statements in other methods, and it has no effect if you do not use `await`.

It controls whether the `await` statement captures the current SynchronizationContext (if there is one). In practice, if you run an `await` statement on the UI thread, then `await task;` will run the code *after* the `await` on the UI thread as well, whereas `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` will run the code after the `await` on a ThreadPool thread.

In your first example:

```
private async Task<string> GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return "Finished!"; // <-- Run on the thread pool
}

private async Task<string> GetStringAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Finished!"; // <-- Run on the captured SynchronizationContext (if any)
}
```

There is a difference in behaviour here, and that is which thread the `return` statement is run on.

In the first method, when the `Task` being `awaited` completes, a message is posted to the *thread pool*, which runs the `return` statement.

In the second method, the `await` statement captures the current SynchronizationContext (which refers to the UI thread), and uses this to run the `return` statement on. This means that a message is posted to the UI thread when 3 seconds have elapsed, telling it to run that `return` statement.

---

In your first snippet which calls `GetStringAsync`:

```
var task = GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
```

The call to `ConfigureAwait` does nothing here, because you're not `await`ing the result. You can remove it with no change.

```
var result = task.GetResult(); // deadlock
```

The UI thread is needed to run the `return` statement in `GetStringAsync`. Since you've blocked it in the call to `GetResult()`, it can't finish the `GetStringAsync` method, and so you've got a deadlock.

---

In your second snippet which calls `GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync`:

```
var task = GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
```

Again, the call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` does nothing, because you're not `await`ing the result.

```
var result = task.GetResult(); // No deadlock
```

This time, `GetStringWithInnerCallConfigureAwaitFalseAsync` does `await ...ConfigureAwait(false)`, and so the code after the `await` is run on the thread pool and not the UI thread. Therefore the UI thread isn't needed to complete this method, and so you can safely (!) block it.

```
Button11.Content = result; // No crash
```

You called this method on the UI thread, and you've never moved off it - you call everything synchronously, there are no `await`s, etc. Therefore you're still on the UI thread at this point

Comment: Thank you, great explanation! The key phrase is *and it has not effect if you do not use await*.